# heroku postgres : creating a database off of a backup creates a empty database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

We're having trouble with the heroku fork command so are manually trying to create a staging environment. I tried creating a new database off of a backup from our prod db but the created db has no rows and is only 6.4MB. The actual backup is 15.7 GB.

I did this via the web console clicking "restore".

Whats the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line, you want to do:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE -a example-staging `heroku pgbackups:url -a example`
```

We use this command every few days, whenever we want the staging database to be replaced with the production database. This comes from: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrate-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups#transfer-to-target-database